# How to respond to programmatic changes of a TextView text

Tags: ios, swift, textview

The TextView delegate is set:

```
textView.delegate = self //self being a UITextViewDelegate
```

but the delegate method doesn't get called when the text is set ***programmatically***

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print(textView.text)
}
```

How to respond to text changes without going reactive?

Comment: You probably need to add something to whatever function is changing the text... Or, possibly subclass `UITextView` and add your own "watching for changes" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried KVO on UITextView,

```
 self.textView1.text = "You are working, but I will change you in 5 seconds"
```

Add your observer

```
self.textView1.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
```

Trigger text change programmatically, just an example do it the way you want.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 5) {
    self.textView1.text = "Changed after some time"
}
```

Override the KVO method.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if object == self.textView1{
     //do your thing here...
    }
}
```

FYI from Apple docs below

> Note: Although the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not
>   support KVO, you can still implement it in the custom objects of your
>   application, including custom views.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html

Answer (score 3):

This is how `UITextField` (and most of UIKit controls) behave- doesn't trigger event when set programatically. It makes sense- lets you avoid recurring, infinite calls.

If you **really** want to be notify when text is changed programatically, you have to subclass `UITextField` and override `text` property (probably `attributedText` also). Then in `didSet` block call delegate method.

Don't forget that `UITextField` inherits from `UIControl`- I would also call `sendActions(for:)` to make target-action mechanism fire.

Comment: The OP is asking about `UITextView`, not `UITextField`. Most of your answer is relevant but unfortunately, `UITextView` does not inherit from `UIControl` so it's not possible to call `sendActions(for:)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. declare your text view variable with `@objc dynamic`
2. declare and hold a variable with type `NSKeyValueObservation`
3. use function `observe(_:changeHandler:)` bind your text view's text property, hold the return value with variable declared in step 2
4. observe changes in changeHandler

example:

```
@objc dynamic private var textView: UITextView!
private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

func bind() {
    observation = observe(\.textView.text, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
        print(object, change)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have misspelled the delegate with textView with _textView

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
        print(textView.text); //the textView parameter is the textView where text was changed
    }
```

Put this in viewDidLoad

```
textView!.delegate = self
```

Comment: It is right, Swift 3.0/3.1 requires that signature.

Comment: @Saranjith Nope. That is the correct signature on Swift 3+